# Difference Between $block and $this magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I have block Class Name `NameSpace1\Test\Block\Test` with method `getTest()`

```
namespace NameSpace1\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function getTest(){
        return "Same Result";
    }
}
```

My Template file name test.phtml with following code

```
<h3>Class: <?php echo get_class($block) ?> Result: (<?php echo $block->getTest() ?>)</h3>
<h3>Class: <?php echo get_class($this) ?> Result: (<?php echo $this->getTest() ?>)</h3>
```

and output the code is following result

[image]

my question is what is difference between $this and $block and which is better to use in my template file both have get same result

Comment: Always use **$block** is given the **current class properties**

Comment: @AmitBera both classes get same results want to know the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless of what object in template you use (`$block` or `$this`) always will be called method from `$block`.

Magic happens in `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::__call()`.

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array([$this->_currentBlock, $method], $args);
}
```

So `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php` is only proxy between template and `$block`, hence `$block` usage is preferred because of direct call.

Additionaly check `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render()` to understand how `$block` is available in template.

Comment: Because in Magento 2 $this refers to the template engine object. (a MagentoFrameworkViewTemplateEnginePhp object by default).