# Why do I need $this in template?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

I have layout

```
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header" 
          template="Vendor_Module::header/notice.phtml" before="-"/>
```

In my template I do the following :

```
echo get_class($block); // Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

echo get_class($this); // Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php
```

**$block** - indicates my block defined in the layout

Why do I need **$this** ?

Comment: you do not need `$this`, And `$block` to access you block methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, you don't.

Alan Storm covered this topic well in his article [Magento 2: $block and $this are NOT Interchangeable](https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-block-and-this-are-not/). Now there are some methods in the `Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php` class you might want, `helper` being an example.

Generally speaking you want to interact with your block class and `$block` is the correct variable to use for that.

As to why it exists, it's just because of how the templating system is built. Some insight about that exists in the Alan Storm article and also check out these questions -  [Difference Between $block and $this magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155816/difference-between-block-and-this-magento-2?rq=1), [Magento 2 Templates: Use `$block` or `$this`?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103096/magento-2-templates-use-block-or-this?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can create helpers in template using $this->helper("\Magento....")

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `$this` inside templates, use `$block` to access your block's methods.