# What are some important concepts to learn in Magento 2 for Interview?

Tags: magento2, development, learn-magento

This is a general question. I don't know whether it's correct to ask here but I hope I will certainly get help with this.

Currently, I'm looking for a Job in Magento. I know Magento is like a Sea :), so I don't know what are the important topics to learn in Magento that will make me the best Magento developer.

For your info, so far I have known the below things in Magento:

- **Installing Magento**
- **Installing plugins**
- **Admin Configuration**
- **Basic module development**
- **Custom theme development**

Apart from the above-said things, what are the important concepts in Magento?

Could anyone please help guide me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the above, you need to know the following:

- The folder structure of Magento themes
- The folder structure of Magento modules
- EAV concept
- Why do we do reindexing
- Observer, Plugin, and Class Override. Which is better to use in which cases
- In Magento 2, what is dependency injection and what are its advantages?
- The factory class and how does it work?
- Basic commands used in Magento 2.
- How to upgrade Magento 2 version.

**Edit 1:**

- What is the difference between id and resource in menu.xml? Can we use different values for these? Which value is used for which purpose?
- Suppose, the table customer_grid_flat has been dropped accidentally. How can it be recovered?
  **Answer:** Simply reindex and enjoy

**Edit 2:**

- Which class is extended by every **controller** class?
- Which class all the **helper** classes extend?
- Which class all the **model** classes extend?
- Difference Between $block and $this magento 2? (Ref: [Magento 2 Templates: Use `$block` or `$this`?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103096/magento-2-templates-use-block-or-this) and 
  [Difference Between $block and $this magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155816/difference-between-block-and-this-magento-2))

I will add more questions here as I recall some more points.

Comment: Thanks. Looking more questions from you.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec, can you please accept my answer also?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Please add some more points so that people like me will learn better.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec, I have updated more questions.

Comment: Thank for adding more questions